# node with soundcloud module

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to access soundcloud api in node, i got error when i try to declare variable for soundcloud api module in node.

this is my code :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    SC = require('soundcloud'); //causing my server won't run

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/indexAPI.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

I got error message like this : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined`

when trying to using soundcloud api, what is 'getUserMedia' mean, why this is happen when i just begin with declare variable for soundcloud api `SC = require('soundcloud');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the Soundcloud library that you'd use in the front end.

Instead you need to use the Node Soundcloud library.

`npm install --save node-soundcloud`

And then `var SC = require('node-soundcloud');`

More info on the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-soundcloud